# Optimizing a method

Tags: c++, optimization

I want to optimized the following method :

```
int getRowWithMinConflicts(int cols)
{
    int minConflicts = MAX;
    int rowWithMinCOnflicts[MAX];
 

    for (int rows = 0; rows < N; rows++)
    {
        rowWithMinCOnflicts[rows] = getConfilictsCount(rows, cols);

        int tempMin = rowWithMinCOnflicts[rows];
        if (tempMin < minConflicts)
        {

             minConflicts = tempMin;
        }
    }


    vector<int> currentRow;


    for (int rows = 0; rows < N; rows++)
    {
        if (rowWithMinCOnflicts[rows] == minConflicts)
        {
            currentRow.push_back(rows);
        }
    }

    return currentRow[rand() % currentRow.size()];
}
```

First i am running a loop to N to save in the array rowWithMinCOnflicts values and keep track which is the minimum

The i run again loop to N to check in the array rowWithMinCOnflicts which entries have the value = "minConflicts" and i add them in vector since i only need their size at the end.
How can I optimize both loops in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use only one loop instead of 2, you might do (I don't think it is faster though):

```
int getRowWithMinConflicts(int cols)
{
    int minConflicts = MAX;
    std::vector<int> candidateRows;
 
    for (int rows = 0; rows < N; rows++)
    {
        int tempMin = getConfilictsCount(rows, cols);

        if (tempMin < minConflicts) {
             candidateRows.clear();
             candidateRows.push_back(row);
             minConflicts = tempMin;
        } else if (tempMin == minConflicts) {
             candidateRows.push_back(row);
        }
    }
    return currentRow[rand() % currentRow.size()];
}
```

And a version without extra memory (but with extra `rand` call):

```
int getRowWithMinConflicts(int cols)
{
    int minConflicts = MAX;
    int bestRow = -1;
    std::size_t minCount = 0;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < N; rows++)
    {
        int tempMin = getConfilictsCount(rows, cols);

        if (tempMin < minConflicts) {
             bestRow = row;
             minCount = 1;
             minConflicts = tempMin;
        } else if (tempMin == minConflicts) {
             ++minCount;
             if (rand() % minCount == 0) {
                 bestRow = row;
             }
        }
    }
    return bestRow;
}
```